# Alamofire 5.0+ MultipartFormData upload bearer token

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift5

I have gotten everything to work on the alamofire multipart form data upload but adding the bearer token.  We use Oauth 2.0 and our files need the token to authenticate in our systems.  I have only found a way to pass the username and password which doesnt work in our current system.  Is there a way to pass the bearer token to the php?

```
   AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
    }

if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
        multipartFormData.append(jpegData, withName: "file", fileName: "image", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }
}, to: "https:website" )
.uploadProgress{ progress in
//print("Upload Progress: \(self.progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
.response { response in
if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
    print("OK. Done")
    print((NSString(data: response.data!, encoding: 
String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String))
}else if response.response?.statusCode == 406{
    print("error")
    DispatchQueue.main.sync{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: 
"Person has not been set up.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "close", style: .default, handler: { action in
             DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.progressUiView.isHidden = true
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}else{
    print(response.response?.statusCode)
}
}
```

Comment: Add the code that you've tried here.

Comment: Added the code.  Sorry its a bit messy.

Comment: Looking at the code I was thinking maybe the `for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }` you might be able to add Bearer token in there

Comment: That is not where you add the bearer token. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the Authorization token to the `headers`. Here's how:

```
let token = "your_token_here"
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    //...
}, to: "https:website", headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"])
    .response { response in
    //...
```

Comment: Wow.  I feel pretty dumb.  That is crazy I couldn't find that anywhere. All I could find was the issues they had with 5.0 on release.  Thank you very much!